# React with express backend

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I want stared to use react with express.
I know, I can use proxy in react package.json. And use my express like api.
But if I want use client routing and server side rendering, where I can show it?

Answer (score 1):

**No need to reinvite the wheel**

[Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) provides server side rendering as well as client routing.

To start install `next`, `react` and `react-dom`

```
npm install --save next react react-dom
```

Next update your `npm scripts` as follow:

```
{
    "scripts": {
       "dev": "next",
       "build": "next build",
       "start": "next start"
    }
}
```

To start start your app, simple run `npm run dev`. To add a new page `/about`, simply create a `about.js` file in the `pages` directory and add the content:

```
const About = ()=> (
    <div>This is the about page</div>
)

export default About
```

simply visit `http://localhost:3000/about` to see the content of the About page displayed.

Take a look at their [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/)

Comment: Thanks, what do you think about Gatsby?

Comment: Gatsby is a static site generator, just static assets. Also it comes with GraphQL. Besides I've yet to have any experience with Gatsby.

Comment: @user10053586 don't forget to accept this answer though if you gain something from it :D